# How to insert child record with master id using apex?

Tags: apex, exception

```
 public PageReference saveMethod(){
      Cluster_Field__c selectedFeields=new Cluster_Field__c ();
      selectedFeields.Selected_Field__c=selectedField;

      selectedFeields.Cluster_Configuration__c=masterid;//this lookup on child
      selectedFeields.Selected_Object__c=storeobject;

      insert selectedFeields;
      PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+selectedFeields.id);
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;

      }
```

Above is my Piece of Apex code to insert child record with master id. When I tried to insert record,then it is throwing below error.

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Cluster Configuration: id value of
>   incorrect type: a0X3600000488D7EAI: [Cluster_Configuration__c]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error statement tells that the value you have provided for the field **'Cluster_Configuration__c'** is of incorrect type. Means it should be of ID data-type and you have provided it of some other data-type.

Also no-where in your code you have queried for the **Master Id** if this is your full code. So how will your code get to know that which is the master id ?

Comment: this is not my full code.

Comment: Check the ID only which you are assigning to your Cluster_configuration__c field. Might be you have assigned id of some other object type by mistake.

Comment: yes.i had assiged wrong id

Answer (score 1):

Your `selectedFeields.Cluster_Configuration__c` will accept an ID of `Cluster_Configuration__c` type of record. So make sure the value you have in `masterid` variable is an ID of a record of type `Cluster_Configuration__c`.

Comment: Masterid's data type is ID,

Comment: I am sure its ID, otherwise you wouldn't be able to save the class. Make sure the ID is of a record of type `Cluster_Configuration__c`